# Most optimized Windows version for an HyperV Virtual Development Machine

Tags: visual-studio, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I need to set up a Virtual Machine using HyperV for programming purposes. Software like Visual Studio 2015 must run well on this VM. So, the first step is to know what Windows version I have to install on this VM.

In your opinion and experience: what version of Windows would be more optimized to run in a virtual machine: Windows 7, 8.1, 10, Server 2012?

Host PC is running on Windows 8.1 (i7, 8GB RAM, SSD&HDD).

This is not a discussion or debate. My only goal is to have a comparison, based on tangible arguments!

Comment: @DavidChing Thank you for your comment, I'll follow your advice and I'll try to install Visual Studio on a VM running Windows 8.1 or 10 (may be a 'N' version). Could you please put your comment as an answer? I'll mark it as THE answer, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler question is which OS provides best performance on raw hardware. There is lots of info on this. Generally that Win 8.1 is better than Win 7 and Win 10 is roughly the same as Win 8.1. Then assume the answer is the same for a Hyper-V guest. This is what I do anyway, and I run Visual Studio only in VM's.